# Recursively find all directories that match a string, and symbolically link folder inside a new directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix, freebsd

I have a large collection of photos, sorted by folder. I'd like to write a script that searches through, finds matching folder names, and creates symbolic links to the folders that match inside a new folder.

Something like this:

```
find /mnt/librarypool/user1/originals -type d -iname "*bbq*" -exec sh -c 'ln -s "{}" "/mnt/mediapool/bbq$("sh basename {}")"' \;
```

(this works, but returns an error, "sh: cannot open basename: No such file or directory")

This will find any folder that matches "bbq" inside /mnt/librarypool/user1/originals and will create a link inside /mnt/mediapool/bbq/ to that folder.

Is there a better way? And how can I clear that error?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use this `find` command:

```sh
find /mnt/librarypool/user1/originals -type d -iname "*bbq*" -exec bash -c \
'for d; do ln -s "$d" "/mnt/mediapool/bbq/${d##*/}"; done' _ {} +
```

- `+` after `find` will pass multiple argument of found directories
- `for d` will loop through those entries
- `${d##*/}` is equivalent of `basename` command as it strips all path info

Comment: This is great. Thanks. How could I extend this to find all video files (*.mov, *.avi, and *.mp4) that match bbq and put all of them in a flat folder inside bbq called videos? currently, I am doing something like this: find /mnt/librarypool/user1/originals -ipath "*bbq*.mov" -exec sh -c 'ln -s "{}" "/mnt/mediapool/bbq/-videos-$(sh basename {})"' \; which works, but also returns an error as above. also there is no way to combine mov, avi, mp4 into one line. And to avoid duplicates, perhaps set the destination filename to the original folder name?

Comment: All of that can be done in shell script but would be too much to change in the nature of the problem you asked. To be able to match multiple extensions use: `find /mnt/librarypool/user1/originals -type d -regextype awk -iregex '.*\.(avi|mp4|mov)$' -exec ...`

Answer (score 0):

On my system at least the `ln` command does create a link with the basename of its target when given a directory as where to put the link, so something like this should indeed work:

```
find /mnt/librarypool/user1/originals \
  -type d -iname "*bbq*" \
  -exec ln -s {} /mnt/mediapool/bbq/ \;
```